# $_POST another attribute than value

Tags: php, post

Is it possible to get some other attribute's value than attribute named value with $_POST

```
example: <option value="FusRo" name="Dah"></option>
```

Normally when i use $_POST['Dah'] The php grabs FusRo (the value).

But I want to grab another attribute's value than attribute named value. I hope you understand.

If I cant use $_POST to grab some other value, is it some other comand i can use?

Another example:
If i use

```
<option value="FusRo" name="Dah"></option>
```

Can I get the "Dah" with $_POST instead of "Fusro" ?

Comment: You should be using `name="smth"` on `select` tag. If this is what you want.

Comment: No you can't, what are you trying to do though?

Comment: Can an `<option>` have a `value=""` attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put your other value in a hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="DahHidden" value="somethingelse" />
```

Then get it from `$_POST` with:

```
$_POST['DahHidden']
```

If this value has to dynamically change based on what's in the `<select>`, then you'll need JavaScript.

If you want to grab the keys from `$_POST` (i.e. the `name` attributes from your form fields), you can iterate over `$_POST` like this:

```
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value) 
    echo $key . ' => ' . $value; // Will print Dah => value (eventually)
```

Note that iterating over `$_POST` will likely produce more output than just that one form element (unless `'Dah'` is the only thing you submitted in your form.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to use JavaScript to modify the posted data, or even simpler use jQuery

then it would look like something like this :

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="skyrim" id="skyrim">
            <input type="text" value="FusRo" name="Dah" data-name="dhovakin" data-race="kajit" />
        <form>

        <script>
            $('#skyrim').submit(function( e ){
                data = {};
                url  = 'http://sandbox.local/testpost.php';

                e.preventDefault();

                $('input, textarea', this).each(function(){

                    var pcs   = $( this ).data();
                    var ename = $( this ).attr('name');

                    if(undefined == data[ ename ] ){
                        data[ ename ] = {};
                        data[ ename ]['_'] = $(this).val();
                    }

                    $.each(pcs, function(k, v){
                        data[ ename ][k] = v;
                    });
                });

                $.ajax({
                    url  : url
                   ,data : data
                   ,type : "POST"

                }).done(function(){

                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above code will add all the attributes starting with `data-` to the post .

the result of the above is :

```
Dah[_]      FusRo     // default value 
Dah[name]   dhovakin  // data-name
Dah[race]   kajit     // data-race
```

Comment: You know, you could seriously write a jQuery plugin with this. I was just about to, but it would probably be copying your code, plus it's simple anyway, so yeah.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST only gives you the names of the field, and their corresponding value, nothing more.

Comment: Ok so If i wanted to have the "name" of the option instead of the value. How would I do?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot post anything else then the "value" of an inputfield.
You could hack your way into it by using javascript. Something like

```
document.getElementById('FORM').onsubmit = function() {
document.getElementById('FIELD').value = document.getElementById('FIELD').customAttribute
}
```

However, if javascript is disabled, your form will submit the wrong values. Not a really solid solution.

Sounds to me more like you will have to redefine your values, I can't really imagine why you would like to alter this behavior.

Comment: I can think of a bunch of reasons to alter this behavior. Values are just one attribute, and sometimes you want to get a lot of data. It's the same reason I'm starting to move away from classes/id's for everything & towards custom attributes.