# Post Input Attribute (Not Value) to Thank You Page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

Is there a way to post attributes other than the value to another page?

For eg: If i have `<option value="Bulgaria" data-key="BG" data-geo="EMEA">Bulgaria</option>`

I know i can post the value and get it on the thank you page with $_POST,

but what if i wanted to get the data-key instead of the value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\_POST another attribute than value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579608/post-another-attribute-than-value)

Comment: use formdata and send it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **only** post the `value` (unless you use AJAX and a bit of manipulation). If you go for the JavaScript route, this would be achieved with something like this:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  data = {};
  url = '';
  e.preventDefault();
  $('input', this).each(function() {
    var pcs = $(this).data();
    var datakey = $(this).attr('data-key');
    if (undefined == data[datakey]) {
      data[datakey] = {};
      data[datakey]['_'] = $(this).val();
    }
    $.each(pcs, function(k, v) {
      data[datakey][k] = v;
    });
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    type: "POST"
  }).done(function() {
    // data-key successfully POSTed
  });
});
```

The better question is **why** are you attempting to do this? If you only want an output of `BG`, use that as the `value`. If you want **both** `Bulgaria` and `BG`, you can make use of a **hidden** input to additionally send the secondary data (as a `value`):

```
<input type="hidden" name="shortcode" value="BG" />
```

Comment: Why flag as a duplicate and then copy some of the answers here anyway?

Comment: To serve as a signpost for a similar question.

Comment: You can post the other attributes *without* Ajax if you have a `submit` or `change` handler that copies the relevant attribute to a hidden input.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#myselect option:selected" ).data("key") or
$( "#myselect option:selected" ).attr("data-key")
```

But you need to send values via js insted of html form send

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you can try it:

**HTML:**

```
<form ... method="post" onsubmit="return form_check()">
    <input type="hidden" name="data_key" id="data_key">
    <input type="hidden" name="data_geo" id="data_geo">
    ...
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function form_check() {
    $('#data_key').val($('#myselect option:selected').data('key')); 
    $('#data_geo').val($('#myselect option:selected').data('geo'));
    return true;
}
```

then in your PHP you'll receive them in `$_POST['data_key']` and `$_POST['data_geo']`.